# Using HTML file as mail body template, images are not showing

Tags: c#, html, mailmessage

I am trying to use a HTML file as mail body template. HTML file has few inline images like LOGO. Everything is fine and I am getting all contents in the HTML file upon receiving the mail, except the images.

An example below  `src="~/Images/logo.png"` but after getting the mail, if I view source in mail client I see like below (using Google SMTP server to send mail).

Reason is pretty clear as why images are not getting displayed (due to the fact that `src` part is getting changed) but not sure how to avoid this.

```
<img title="MyCompany" class="xxxx" alt="MyCompany"
src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/VigKoQr9DXTS3UveuswmpxB6iEAO5rcVwSrrVUptfWGAeYQFugjcKDZxDZbB6g=s0-d-e1-ft#http://~/Images/logo.png">
```

Any solution for this? How can I get the actual images being displayed? 
Thank You.

Comment: It looks like Google's SMTP server is injecting a URL into your SRC attribute.  However, your image URL makes no sense.  Where is this image hosted?  Have you tried using an absolute URL?

Comment: @raduation, absolutely that's evident but not sure why the heck so. that's a plain HTML file which has the `<img alt="Mycompany" src="~/Images/logo.png" />` and nope didn't tried using absolute url though

Comment: Where is that image?  How is that image supposed to be addressed on the email receiver's machine?  Try an absolute URL.

Comment: @raduation, Ah!!! forgot to mention ... all present inside project in a folder named `Images` under root folder obviously.

Comment: @raduation, Hmm ... makes sense totally. Now I see what you are talking. let me try that once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the solution!

For email template you should provide absolute url for the image.

Ex: `<img src="http://ngm.nationalgeographic.com/2015/11/climate-change/which-species-will-thrive/img/12-bengal-tiger-1024.jpg" >`

Comment: That's alright but how would it be if the image is inside your project?

Comment: you should upload that image to online storage like dropbox or some other storage and provide that url in the image source.

Comment: @SrikanthReddy : then its better to send that via his Gmail Account

Comment: Make sense ... it has to be absolute URL.

Comment: Just to add a note `~/` is a .net concept not a web standard. When in a dynamic context the path is generated and rendered to the output. Since this is a static HTML file the `~/` is left as is. This, of course, doesn't change the fact that an absolute URL is needed.